# How to use notifySetDataChange in adapter for refresh listview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I used fragment in my app and i'm using SQLite to save local data. But when I finished saving data, and I `swipe` the page, my listView is not refreshed with new data (Only showing old data). I have tried to provide a method `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter, but it's not working.

My Base Adapter class :

```
public class LocalDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<LocalDataBean> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public LocalDataAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<LocalDataBean> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setItem(ArrayList<LocalDataBean> data){
        this.data = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView nama_konsumen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nama_konsumen);
        TextView no_telp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_telp);
        TextView no_hp_cdma = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_hp_cdma);
        TextView no_hp_gsm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_hp_gsm);

        LocalDataBean obj = (LocalDataBean) getItem(position);

        nama_konsumen.setText(obj.getNamaKonsumen());
        no_telp.setText(obj.getNoTelp());
        no_hp_cdma.setText(obj.getNoCMDA());
        no_hp_gsm.setText(obj.getNoGSM());

        return v;
    }

}
```

My fragment class :

```
public class LocalDataFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Activity act;
    SQLHandlerBean utilSql;

    ArrayList<LocalDataBean> localdatabean = new ArrayList<LocalDataBean>();
    LocalDataAdapter adapter;

    ListView list;

    public static final String TAG = LocalDataFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_local_data, null);
        act = getActivity();

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewLocalData);

        utilSql = new SQLHandlerBean(this.act);
        adapter = new LocalDataAdapter(act, localdatabean);

        localdatabean = new ArrayList<LocalDataBean>();

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (utilSql.ReadAllLocalData().size() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(act, "DATA EMPTY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            localdatabean = utilSql.ReadAllLocalData();
            Log.e(TAG, "TOTAL DATA : "+localdatabean.size());
            adapter.setItem(localdatabean);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Is `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` placement correct?

Comment: Are you using viewpager?

Comment: i guess tthe localdatabean didnt chnaged , plz log it before notifying adapetr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the placement is not in the right place.
As you have placed the `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside of the `onCreateView()` method. It will be only invoked 1st time the fragment is launched.

Rather you can add a refresh button in your layout (or in you action bar). And along with the insertion/deletion method of the data, place the `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the bottom of the click event of that button.

By doing this user can refresh the page whenever they want.

And if you want to refresh the page by swipping the view then, SwipeRefreshLaoyout could be a perfect alternative.

You can check [this](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/) blog.